# In a method that takes an interface, how could I make the method take any interface's derived interface?

Tags: c#, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

So I have an interface relationship like this:

```
public interface IPlayer {
    public List<Card> LoseCards();
}

public interface IPlayer_WithPersonalDeck : IPlayer {
    public void AddCardsToPersonalDeck(List<Card>);
}
```

I also have a generic command interface that is inherited to command players

```
public interface ICommands<T> {
    public Object? execute (T)
    public Object? execute (T, T);
}

public class BasePlayerCommands : ICommands<IPlayer> {
    public virtual Object? execute (IPlayer) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    public virtual Object? execute (IPlayer executor, IPlayer target) { throw new NotSupportedException(); } 
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
public class TakeCardsFromPlayer_AndAddToDeckCommand : BasePlayerCommands {
    public override List<Card> execute(IPlayer_WithPersonalDeck executor, IPlayer target) {
        return executor.AddCardsToPersonalDeck(target.LoseCards());
    }
}
```

This does not work as `TakeCardsFromPlayer_AndAddToDeckCommand` does not find a suitable `execute` method to overload. Obviously this is because I am using `IPlayer_WithPersonalDeck` instead `IPlayer`. However, since that interface derives from `IPlayer`, why can't I substitute it in?

Doesn't this follow the Liskov Principle, since any class that implements `IPlayer_WithPersonalDeck` means they are also an `IPlayer`?

So to me, `execute()` shouldn't care that it's a derived interface since it shares a base interface of `IPlayer` like it requires.

Any explanation as to why this doesn't work as I thought would be appreciated, as well as how I can work around this problem.

I would like to avoid having to implement a class that uses `ICommand<IPlayer_WithPersonalDeck>` as not all my commands may need both players to have a deck, if that's possible.

A solution I have right now is to cast an `IPlayer` to the correct interface inside of `execute`. Its unsafe though as any `IPlayer` could be passed to it and can throw errors if the user isn't careful as not every player has a deck.

Comment: Interfaces are contracts, promises of what a type implementing them would have... **Exactly**